# Understanding the explicit homotopy of Exercise 1.1.10

Tags: homotopy-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

From the isomorphism $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ it follows that loops in $X \times \{y_0\}$ and $x_0 \times \{Y\}$ represent commuting elements of $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)).$ Construct an explicit homotopy demonstrating this.

And here is one of the solutions given in the following link (I am looking for the second solution: ) [Commuting elements in product fundamental group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253279/commuting-elements-in-product-fundamental-group?rq=1):

"I see now what my problem was, I never understood the complete formulas for the constant loop homotopy, but I found it in Lee. We have a homotopy $a \sim x_0 \cdot a$ by

$H_t(s) = \begin{cases} x_0 & 0 \leq s \leq t/2 \\  a(\frac{2s - t}{2 - t}) & t/2 \leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}$

and for the other side we have a homotopy $b \sim b \cdot y_0$ given by

$G_t(s) = \begin{cases} b(\frac{2s}{2 - t}) & 0 \leq s \leq 1 - t/2 \\ y_0 & 1 - t/2 \leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}$.

Thus the homotopy we are looking for then is $J_t(s) = (H_t(s), G_t(s))$. $J_0(s) = (a(s),b(s))$, $J_1(s) = ((x_0 \cdot a)(s), (b \cdot y_0)(s))$ and $J_t(0) = J_t(1) = (x_0, y_0)$. We can construct a similar based homotopy from $(a \cdot x_0, y_0 \cdot b)$ to $(a, b)$ and since homotopy is an equivalence relation we have finally have a homotopy from $(a \cdot x_0, y_0 \cdot b)$ to $(x_0 \cdot a, b \cdot y_0)$."

**My question is:**

Why in the homotopy between $b$ and $b.y_0,$ which is $G_s(t),$ why in the first part $s \leq 1 - \frac{t}{2},$ could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "reason" is that: $$\frac{2s}{2-t}>\frac{2-t}{2-t}=1$$When $s>1-t/2$ so $b(2s/2-t)$ isn't defined. $1-t/2$ is the point at which we stop, giving $b(1)=y_0$, in the user's homotopy.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, why it is not just $t\2,$ why $1- t\2$? Also, I believe that this homotopy should begin at the end point of the first homotopy, am I correct?

Comment: @Brain To your first question, it should (and more is demanded, because the homotopy must be based) but $2/t$ won’t suffice as, with $s=2/t$, $2s/2-t$ isn’t equal to $1$ (or zero)

Comment: I mean $\frac{t}{2}$ not  $\frac{2}{t}$

Comment: why "$1-t/2$ is the point at which we stop, giving $b(1)=y_0$" .... what calculation did the author of the answer do in his mind to choose this point and not just choosing $\frac{t}{2}$?

Comment: What is the line that the user calculated its equation to get this equation?

Comment: @Brain Whoops, I meant $t/2$ not $2/t$. I can’t speak for the author but I suppose they just solved the equation $2s/(2-t)=1$ and found $s=1-t/2$

Comment: Yeah but why in the first homotopy we had $s \leq \frac{t}{2}$ while in the second one we have $s \leq 1- \frac{t}{2}$? looks like we are taking the inverse which I do not understand why.

Comment: if you look at this video on min 14 you will understand what I wanna say https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVxPwbUCep0&list=PLCgncMh0TrClLOU991FDEQK5LF_Aqm4FS&index=5 I am asking in our case here is s and t ranging also from 0 to 1?

Comment: Do you know who is Lee , the author of the book the author is referring to? I can look at the book, maybe this will help me.

Comment: I think I know now that the author is starting the second homotopy from $(s,t) = (1,0)$ to the point $(s,t) = (1/2 , 1)$ but why he is doing this?

Comment: @Brain I think you’re really overthinking this. In the first homotopy, $s=t/2$ has $(2s-t)/(2-t)=0$ so $a(0)=x_0$ and all is well. When defining homotopies in this way, the only thing to worry about is that the values on the two ‘pieces’ agree. Jack Lee is a significant textbook author, I don’t know which of his books is referred to here (and it doesn’t matter, I don’t think you need to look at this book for this purpose). Your final comment doesn’t make sense to me

Comment: the first homotopy is just controlling ‘how long’ the loop is ‘doing $a$’ and how long the loop is being constant at $x_0$, as if on a slider from $0\to1$. The special $s$ values (e.g. $1-t/2$) just mark the boundary between $x_0$ and commencing the loop $a$, and these are *deliberately* adjusted with time so that at $t=0$ we have $a$ always but at $t=1$ we have $x_0\cdot a$. Drawing a picture is recommended if this still confuses you (but do please be wary of overthinking: the homotopy does its job, and it is well defined. In a sense, that’s all we care about)

Comment: I was able to understand that the second homotopy is starting from $s = 1,$ I am pretty sure from what I am saying. My question now is why he is doing this? what is the relation betweenthe first and the second homotopy in terms of the intervals of $s$ and $t,$ should the second homotopy start after the first homotopy with respect to s? note that both loops depend on s

Comment: it is my first time to deal with an ordered pair homotopy ..... is it the same as if we compose 2 homotopies? I honestly do not know.

Comment: I think I understood a little bit what I am asking about.

Comment: @Brain Homotopy is an equivalence relation. An ordered pair of homotopies can be made to be one homotopy, just as you will have seen an ordered pair of loops or paths can be made into one loop or path. I’m not sure what you mean when you say you’re looking for a ‘relation’ but the two are doing very similar things ($a\simeq x0\cdot a$ and $b\simeq b\cdot y_0$)